# Map the hibernate query results in a separate class with OneToMany relationship

Tags: java, hibernate

I have two tables in my database Employee and EmployeeAssets. EmployeeAssets table holds information about the assets held by each employee. The schema of these tables is like this:

```
//Table Employee
int code (Primary Key)
String name
String address

//Table EmployeeAssets
int rowId (Primary Key, Auto Increment)
int employeeCode (Foreign key, code of Employee table)
String assetCode
```

I am using hibernate 4.x/MySQL to access these tables. I have defined the JAVA class to map each table into entity classes Employee and EmployeeAssets. Now, I want to report the name of each employee and the list of assets held by him. So I create a java class like this:

```
class Report {
  public String employeeName;
  @OneToMany(cascade= CascadeType.ALL, mappedBy="employeeName")
  @JoinColumn(name="assetCode")
  public Set<String> assetCodes;
};
```

My hibernate query looks like:

```
session.createQuery("select e.name as employeeName, a.assetCode as assetCode from Employee e, EmployeeAssets a where e.code = a.employeeCode").setResultTransformer(Transformers.aliasToBean(Report.class)).list()
```

But above query does not work and I am getting an exception as:

```
org.hibernate.PropertyNotFoundException: Could not find setter for assetCode on class com.test.model.impl.Report
```

I am sure that this should be very much possible through hibernate but I am not able to figure out how. Any help/suggestion is much appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: A OneToMany is between entities. String is not an entity. You need a Set<EmployeeAsset>. I have a hard time understanding why you have a Report entity. That should be inside the Employee entity. The Report entity shouldn't exist at all: you don't have any report table. You query should simply be `select distinct e from Employee e left join fetch e.assets`;

Comment: @JBNizet I do not want to modify the Employee entity because I do not need that information every time when I fetch Employee. Also, I just want to map a single column from EmployeeAsset, do I need to map the whole EmployeeAsset entity? Is that possible to map only the selected columns?

Comment: OneToMany and JoinColumn must be used in entities. They're used to map entities to tables. They make no sense outside of entities. What's wrong with loading the entities themselves instead of just 2 columns? Not saying you should never do that. But if the simple, obvious solution works fine and is fast enough, then you shouldn't try doing something else. If you really want to read instances of Report, then you'll have to construct them by yourself based on the list of rows that the query returns.

Comment: To react on your updated comment: ToMany associations are lazy-loaded by default. So loading en employee won't load its assets, even if employee has an association with Asset. The assets will only be loaded if you call a method on the collection of assets. And you're using the term "mapping" wrong. "mapping" consists in annotating entities to tell JPA how to map them with tables. What you want is to transform the rows returned by a query into instances of a non-entity class called Report. That's not mapping, and mapping annotations can't be used to do that.

Comment: Thanks a lot @JBNizet. That clarifies things for me. I appreciate your help.

Comment: @JBNizet If I reference the set of Entities with OneToMany mapping as you suggested with lazy fetch policy, then what happens when we do session.update on parent entity? For example, if there are four distinct entries for employee id 1 in asset table and this time when call update I have two more entries in set, so after update will it become six asset or it will delete the previous 4 and only latest two will exist in table?

Comment: It depends on many things. What the cascade option is, how you created the object you update, etc. You should generally not call update(). Get a managed entity, modify it, and that's all. JPA updates the database automatically.